# MongoDB excluding fields from aggregate, is that possible?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to exclude some fields from my booking aggregate.

{
 "user":0, 
 "paymentType":0, 
 "_id":0
}

without this it works great, but with it I get the errors:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
    "code" : 40323,
    "codeName" : "Location40323"
} : aggregate failed
```

Is this possible to do, or can I only do it with find() ?

```
db.getCollection('booking').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        checkin : {$lte: (1512145439)},
        checkout: {$gte: (1483203600)},
    }
}, 
    {
     "user":0, 
     "paymentType":0, 
     "_id":0
    }
, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "users"
    }   
}, {
    $unwind: "$user"
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "country": "$users.country"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "users": 0
    }    
}, {
    $project: {
        "booking": 0
    }
}])
```

If I do like this, it will exclude the fields:

```
db.getCollection('booking').find({},        
        {
         "user":0, 
         "paymentType":0, 
         "_id":0
        })
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `{ $project : { "user":0, "paymentType":0, "_id":0 } }` ? Are you sure to exclude `user` field as you are using the field in `$lookup` ?

Comment: @Veeram yes you are right - I needed the $project in front - it was me who didnt understand the correct use of $project.  Thanks again :)   once I did like this "$project":{property : 1, source : 1, checkin : 1} then it worked.
Please post reply :)

Comment: Yes @Veeram if you do not project the match fields, key fields, lookup fields then it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use the field exclusion/inclusion inside the `$project` stage in aggregation pipeline.

On a side note use `$addFields` when you need to add new fields / overwrite fields and use `$project` when you want to limit fields.

From the docs,

> The $addFields stage is equivalent to a $project stage that explicitly
>   specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new
>   fields.

Comment: Veeram, just to understand the syntax.  How come  $unwind: "$user" works but $unwind: {"$user"} does not?  Do you have to exclude {} when its single parms or just not use them in unwind?

Comment: Yes you've to exclude `{}` which represents document. Documents are key value pair.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#syntax) or [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields)

> **$unset and $project** : The $unset is an alias for the $project stage that removes/excludes fields

```
{ $unset: [ "<field1>", "<field2>", ... ] }
```

```
{ $project: { "<field1>": 0, "<field2>": 0, ... } }//Return all but the specified fields
```